# How to select a word from a dictionary which has the highest score and print it

Tags: c++

Hey I'm trying to make a function, the function its self finds the word with the highest score and then list that word, I'm currently using a vector to find the word with the highest score but I wish to get the word from my dictionary.

Comment: Please state what the problem is (compilation error? bad output?). Add example of expected output.

Comment: What is the problem? The code looks correct, apart from the `std::string` vs `Word` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector you store your words in is a vector of `std::string`, and not a vector of `Word` pointers. So you can't use `compare_by_score` as it expects the latter kind of arguments and not the first.

Either store `Word` pointers in the vector, or change the `compare_by_score` function to take `const std::string&` arguments and then in the function convert it to `Word` objects.

Comment: But it doesn't need to be `const &` , right? The only rule is that it won't modify the elements.

Comment: @tomi.lee.jones You might want to check e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: I have just quoted it. : )

Comment: my `word_list` is just a temporary list of words to test if it works, I have a bigger list which can get grabbed using `GetWord()`